# Convert the column '6/25/2019 10:06:49 AM' to date type from object type in pandas

Tags: pandas

**I need to convert this '6/25/2019 10:06:49 AM' into date datatype which is actually in object type.**

```
df["TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TIME"], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

I have tried using this but it is throwing the below error.

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: You need to remove the extra spaces in the column before converting it to date format.**

***To remove the extra spaces:***

```
df.TIME = df.TIME.str.rstrip()
```

**Now try to convert to date datatype using below codes:**

```
df["TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TIME"])
(or)
df["TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TIME"], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

**NOTE: %H is used for 24hrs and %I is used for 12hrs.**